# How to get value of django form within that same form before submission?

Tags: python, django, forms, recursion, django-forms

I'm creating a django form with 3 choice fields. I want the 3rd choice field (object field) to populate based on the first 2 choice fields. Boiling it down, I guess my question would be how do I get the values of the first 2 choice fields so I can use those values within the same form.py before submitting?

Here is what my forms.py looks like, which is currently giving me the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded":

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    season = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control test"}),
        label="season",
        choices=SEASON_CHOICES,
    )
    episode = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}), label="episode"
    )

    object = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="object",
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        form = MyForm()
        season = form.cleaned_data.get["season"]
        episode = form.cleaned_data.get["episode"]
        try:
            snow = Snowflake()
            snow_data = snow.query(
                f"""select * from modern_family"""
            )

            object_data = snow.query(
                f"""select * from {season}.{episode}"""
            )
            snow.close()
            self.fields["episode"].choices = [(sd[0], sd[0]) for sd in snow_data]
            self.fields["object"].choices = [(sd[0], sd[0]) for sd in object_data]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: I suggest you use `.format()` on your SQL code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319082/18020941 You get the recursion error because you initialize another instance of the same class, in the `__init__()` method. This is an endless loop. You are also asking for `cleaned_data` from an empty form, what exactly do you expect this to return?

Comment: Whoops, to late to edit. Sorry. To answer your question; override the `clean()` method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean

Comment: form= MyForm() in ini is wrong. Probably simply self ?

Comment: @nigel239 thanks for the suggestion, but not sure how the clean() method would allow me to populate the 3rd choice field dependent on the 1st and 2nd. I've tried following the doc's example, but it's not doing quite what I was hoping...

Comment: @MaximDanilov I've tried replacing self, but I get a different error saying that My form doesn't have the attribute "cleaned_data"
Any other suggestions? Thank you both!

Comment: @ShinheePark Why not do this logic in a view anyways? Or hell, even on the model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is create a 'conditional' form, where early elements dictate the format or presence of later elements.

Django doesn't handle this use case out of the box, as views containing forms are created server-side and delivered to the client browser. Django has no default visibility over what happens on the client page, unfortunately. `cleaned_data` is what is produced by a submitted form, not one currently being filled out, so your approach won't work as is.

Usually dynamic elements such as conditional forms are handled client side by javascript, as the elements on the page can be read before submission using onchange() or listener functions attached to the form elements.

There are a few approaches to try

1. Split the form into two, and deliver a constructed third drop down in a separate view and form - for this you only need django
2. Use HTMX or Ajax to make a call via javascript back to the server, then alter the third dropdown element appropriately based on the response.  HTMX may be a good choice for this as you can deliver the new dropdown HTML directly from a django template. This is a good approach if you need to do server side calculations on what options should be available in the third dropdown.
3. Use javascript alone to read the values of the first two dropdowns and amend the third dropdown. A good approach if all the info you need to edit the third dropdown is contained in the page.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful response! This led me to think about it in the right way, and I ended up splitting the form into two. Works like a charm.